# select certain words from list of string after comma

Tags: vb.net

What i want to do is take particular values from a list of strings and store them into variables for that particular index.

Com317,subject,1,20,M,year1

the example is what is contained in each index of the list of strings. I want to select the 1 and the 20 from this list and store them into 2 variables. Been trying to do this with a for each loop but I'm not sure how i can single out these 2 values

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split function to accomplish this:

```
Dim s As String = "Com317,subject,1,20,M,year1"
Dim splitVals As String() = s.Split(",")

MessageBox.Show(splitVals(2)) ' 1
MessageBox.Show(splitVals(3)) ' 20
```

Comment: yea i just got it :) using the same function, thanks for confirmation that this is the way it should be done

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like that should works
This is pseudocode (I dont have VS installed on this computer, so check for bugs)

```
dim st as string
st = "Com317,subject,1,20,M,year1"

dim var1 as integer
dim var2 as integer

var1 = CInt(st.split(",")(2))
var2 = CInt(st.split(",")(3))
```